# Why does my while loop not enter the if statement inside it?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Rock paper scissors pt 2...

I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game and so far I have this:

```
from random import randint
print("Rock...")
print("Paper...")
print("Scissors...")

player_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0

while player_wins < 3 and computer_wins < 3:
    print(f"{computer_wins} to {player_wins}")

    player1 = input("Player 1, make your move: ").lower()
    computer_choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computer_choice = randint(0, 2)
    computer = [computer_choices[computer_choice]]
    print(computer)

    if player1 == computer:
        print("It's a tie!")

    elif player1 == "rock":
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("player1 wins!")
            player_wins += 1
        elif computer == "paper":
            print("computer wins!")
            computer_wins += 1

    elif player1 == "paper":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("player1 wins!")
            player_wins += 1
        elif computer == "scissors":
            print("computer wins!")
            computer_wins += 1

    elif player1 == "scissors":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("computer wins!")
            computer_wins += 1
        if computer == "paper":
            print("player1 wins!")
            player_wins += 1
    else:
        print("something went wrong")
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is have it take an input, pick a random choice, and then compare the choices. I have the first two parts down, where it picks a choice and takes the input, but it doesn't enter the if statements inside the while loop. It just keeps going forever.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The computer choice is always a list and you are comparing it to a string.

Change this line:

```
computer = [computer_choices[computer_choice]]  # list with one string item
```

To this:

```
computer = computer_choices[computer_choice]  # string
```

The game works correctly with this change.